# Phone travel charger for powering circuits dangers

Tags: power-supply, safety, charger, fuses

I am thinking of using a phone travel charger to power a circuit.Ratings:
input:110-240VAC(my outlet has 220volts) 50/60Hz 0,3A
output:DC 5,2volts at 400mA
The problem is that 220 V are of course dangerous and I 'm not sure of how safe is my charger.
My question is:do phone travel chargers have fuses inside them in case there might be a component failure and an electric shock would become possible?
I also opened the case a few times ,but I didn't modify anything inside and before I put it back last time,the circuitry was intact.
EDIT:Here are the requested images-
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A fuse is used to cut the connection to the 220V in case something breaks in the circuit, in order to prevent fire, it does NOT protect you as a user from the 220V. This is done using a small transformer and possibly an optical device. These give the required isolation from 220 V. As mentioned below, assuming this is a good quality device !

Comment: BTW, the fact that you can open the case (without damaging it !?) is not a promising sign. Usually good quality adapters are welded shut and cannot be opened without damaging the case.

Comment: Yes,it could be unscrewed easily and it had some plastic latches that keep it tight.Anyway,the phone wasn't cheap at all.

Comment: Daniel - plese provide model and brand details - country would be useful. There are MANY VERY dangerous adaptors 'out there' that could kill you and your gear. A good brand product will usually be OK. | QC passed is essentiallyt meaningless. alas - if that is the only marking sthen odds are quality cannot be depended on. Can you post a clear sharp good quality photo of charger ionternals and phone + charger externaally.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Is the circuitry inside ok?

Comment: Daniel - it looks more competent than many but is a low cost hand built product. That is not necessarily bad in itself but raises doubt about the things than cannot be checked visually.  They have isolated high and low voltage moderately well with the gap in the PCB copper area and have added a slot where the low to high voltage feedback optocoupler is to increase "creepage distance". These two aspects show they understand what is needed and have made efforts in the right direction. What cannot be seen is the quality of the switching supply transformer construction and this is crucial. ....

Comment: .... It is possible to "cut corners" badly on such things to save a small amount of money and you cannot tell directly if they have done so. **BUT** there is another area where they **HAVE** cut corners to save money (or just do not care) and this suggests that you may be unwise to trust them with your life. There is NO input RFI (EMC) filtering at all on the mains input and the supply would not pass modern certification requirements for this reason alone, let alone others which may be unseen. The diodes at top left [**here**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/l0tWN.jpg) rectify the mains, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that 220 V are of course dangerous and I 'm not sure of how safe is my charger. My question is:do phone travel chargers have fuses inside them in case there might be a component failure and an electric shock would become possible?

It looks more competent than many, but is a low cost hand built product.
That is not necessarily bad in itself but raises doubt about the things than cannot be checked visually.

They have isolated high and low voltage moderately well with the gap in the PCB copper area and have added a slot where the low to high voltage feedback optocoupler is to increase "creepage distance". These two aspects show they understand what is needed and have made efforts in the right direction. What cannot be seen is the quality of the switching supply transformer construction and this is crucial. It is possible to "cut corners" badly on such things to save a small amount of money and you cannot tell directly if they have done so.

**BUT** there is another area where they **HAVE** cut corners to save money (or just do not care) and this suggests that you may be unwise to trust them with your life.
There is NO input RFI (EMC) filtering at all on the mains input and the supply would not pass modern certification requirements for this reason alone, let alone others which may be unseen. The diodes at top left [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0tWN.jpg) rectify the mains.

In the photos below, I have mirrored thge top PCB left for right so that the layout matches the underside view. The only filtering for switching noise is the resistor at top let and the capacitor at bottom left.  The resistor also serves to limit the inrush current when 1st plugging ioj the power supply. The amount of noise filtering would not be enough to meet regulatory requirements.

The high to low voltage PCB copper gap can be seen and the slot where the opto isolator is. I've seen MUCH worse than this.

If you have used this with your phone for some while and the phone does not die then they MAY have made a good job of the transformer. Any such supply is a gamble but this is *potentially* better than many. Whether *potentially* and "**actually**" match is unknowable.

[image]

DanielPSUV3.jpg

Comment: The phone did indeed die some time in the past.I will change the charger with a branded one(LG),which cannot be opened without damaging the case.

Answer (score 2):

An **unmodified** and **genuine** charger actually made by an **internationally renowned** cell phone company such a Nokia or Samsung will be very safe under normal operating conditions. Apple ones are great too, but there are many, many counterfeits about. Even if it is top-drawer, I still would not tempt fate by using it when water is about, or any other situation that could involve low impedance connections to a human.

There are counterfeits and all sorts of junk flying around. Fuses won't necessarily save you from electrocution- if there is an internal breach of the galvanic isolation barrier (say due to bad design, component failure, modification or debris inside bridging the gap) then the fuse (if any) could happily pass enough current to kill you. If the adapter power is flipped it may not even be in the circuit. The purpose of a fuse is to allow the adapter itself to fail gracefully without excessive drama.

I have personally taken apart several chargers with counterfeit markings (both the company name/logo and the safety agency markings were counterfeit) and those particular ones were extremely dangerous. They would never pass safety agency approval. I would never give one to a kid or to any other human I cared about. I might plug them in for test purposes, but would keep a careful eye on them. Also junky electrically- noisy output voltage and a lot of conducted EMI.

Aside from reliability and the quality of the power (cheaply made ones may not have OVP, so a failure of a solder joint could render your $1000 phone into trash), the two main dangers are electrical shock and fire. Those dangers are mitigated by careful design meeting safety agency guidelines, listed or approved materials for every safety-critical application and thorough testing. For example, the approval documents will list the approved suppliers of the polyester tape and wire used in the transformer. They must use material only from those suppliers  (who, in turn, follow QA procedures internally). Junk adapters will use whatever is cheapest- maybe even rejected material from top-tier suppliers.

Comment: I suggest that you make that "... reputable ..." or name-brand cellphone company and even give examples as Asmyldof did BECAUSE he so far says his phone was not cheap aaand has said brand is "Galaxy" as if that was significant (which it MAY be but ....) - so I think you have a job ahead to convince him and need to lean (even) more topwards the safe side.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Changed to 'internationally renowned'. You're right, it was not strong enough. Most cell phones have some brand name on them even if it's not well known.

Answer (score 2):

If your charger is branded (Siemens, Samsung, Nokia, Apple, HTC, etc etc) and/or has a UL/TüV listing that can be taken seriously you can use the charger's 5VDC output for whatever you want.

If you overload it, it is possible it may break, but with many 5VDC chargers that's unlikely, but it must certainly not create shorts or hazards on the 230VAC side.

If your charger is Cheap-Special-Offer-Crap from eBay, then it's anybody's guess how safe it is. Even if it has a UL/TüV/Similar marking, because cheap crap means there was very likely no actual testing, it's probably just a sticker/stamp-mould the manufacturer used without official permission to do so.

Comment: The charger belongs to a Galactic phone , but it has no brand on it.There was a marking on it:"QC passed" or something like that.Does it mean anything?

Comment: @DanielTork QC Passed means some guy stuck a sticker on it that in their internal Quality Control department he found it to be okay. It has no significance at all. If there's never been any type of certified label like "UL" or "TüV" that's worrisome. If they didn't even put "CE" on it, which you can without test if you stuck to the design rules, then that's very worrisome. I Don't know the "Galactic" brand, so that doesn't mean anything to me other than that it might not be a very stringently checked brand of equipment.

Answer (score 0):

The big risk is that the transformer has not been constructed correctly. There may not have been sufficient insulation in the first place and/or bad winding processes may have damaged the insulation that is there. Unfortunately there is no good way to test or inspect said insulation, you can do high-voltage insulation tests but they are not conclusive.

The best you can do is buy power supplies of known-brand from large vendors in countries with strong product liability laws.

Your power supply's label has absolutely nothing on it to identify the manufacturer which is concerning to say the least.